# Synchronizing two SQL Server databases using MS Sync Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I have one central SQL Server database which can be offline from time to time. I have a desktop application using Local DB Cache (SQL CE) to synchronize with the central database and I also have a web application with its own SQL Server that I'd also would like to keep synchronized. All synchronizations must be bidirectional.

Is there a way to synchronize my central database with web application's database in the same way as I synchronize my central database with desktop client?

I know about collaboration scenarios and peer-to-peer synchronization but I would like to avoid manual provisioning of databases. I'd like to use integrated sql server 2008 change tracking just like in the SQL CE <--> SQL Server scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question once: [sync framework server to server synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420312/sync-framework-server-to-server-synchronization)

In  the end i did the syncronization myself(using stored procedures) and it wasn't that hard. Or you can use [replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)(in my project there was a term to use as little traffic as we can, so i've implemented my own mechanism for my needs)